# How to stop light from seeping through meshes?

Tags: lighting, unreal, shadows, 3d-modeling

I'm trying to make a giant minecraft world but light keeps seeping through everything, as every block is paper-thin. Is there a way to increase its thickness?
[image][image]

Notice the edges of the meshes. Light is seeping through.^^

Comment: Can you walk us through the steps you took to make this scene? This looks like it could be a light mapping artifact, but that's not fully clear from the image alone. A good guideline is to try to share a "Minimal Complete Verifiable Example": that is, a complete description of the steps someone would need to take to reproduce the problem starting from a new, empty project.

Comment: If you have Blender:
1. Make a plane
2. Extrude it a bunch of times in different directions to create some boxes
3. Export as an FBX
4. Import into UE5's default world
5. Close up on the edges of the mesh.

Light should leak through...

Comment: Can you clarify, do these planes intersect? So for instance a wall could continue down below a floor or the floor continue past the wall, rather than meeting at a welded (manifold) joint? Is there some minimum size/complexity of a scene needed to observe this artifact, or does it happen even for a single cube sitting on a plane? (This is the "minimal" part of an MCVE) What units are you using for the spacing between voxels? (This can be relevant if the lightmap texel resolution is just a few texels per face at this size)

Comment: Nevermind, I think I figured it out. My lightmass res was too low on the mesh.

Comment: Want to document your solution as an Answer below?